# A formula to find the size of a matrix after convolution

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

If my input size is 5x5, the stride is 1x1, and the filter size is 3x3 then I can compute on paper that the final size of the convolved matrix will be 3x3.

But, when this input size changes to 28x28, or 50x50 then how can I compute the size of the convolved matrix on paper? Is there any formula or any trick to do that?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a formula (see the details in [cs231n class](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv)):

```
W2 = (W1 - F + 2*P) / S + 1
H2 = (H1 - F + 2*P) / S + 1
```

where  `W1xH1` is the original image size, `F` is the filter size, `S` is the stride and `P` is one more parameter - the *padding size*. Also note that result channel size equals to the number of filters.