# Understanding output of Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution, max-pooling

I have been trying to understand Convolutional Neural Network but I mess up with its output size.

The Formula is pretty much straightforward but I still end up confusing myself. I have learned from many sources on the Internet like deeplearning.ai of AndrewNg.

So here is where I am getting confused.

`OutputSize  = InputSize - Filter + 1`

If my `InputSize` is `11 x 11 x 16` and I use `max pool` with `filter size 2`. By math my shape should be `5.5 x 5.5 x 16`.

Will this float value `(5.5)` rounded off or will it be taken as `5` when you feed it?

Comment: Where is that division coming from? And are you even thinking in the right direction? The input is filtered to produce the output; hence the input size determines the output size.

Comment: division is coming from from pooling

Answer (score 0):

The formula that you described is a partial case for a specific setting. A [general formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47274957/712995) is this:

```
W2 = (W1 - F + 2*P) / S + 1
H2 = (H1 - F + 2*P) / S + 1
```

As you can see, it depends not only on the filter size `F`, but also the stride `S` and the padding size `P` (so your formula is just for `P=0` and `S=1`).

In case of max pooling, `S` is usually `2`, so that the pooling performs image downsampling. The result depends solely on the padding:

- If `P=0`, the result will be `5x5x16` (i.e., it's ceiling the value).
- If `P=1`, the result will be `6x6x16`.
- Any bigger padding doesn't make any sense, but you can calculate the output size using the formula above.

Here's a sample code in keras:

```py
input = Input(shape=(11, 11, 16))
print(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='valid')(input).shape)
# >>> (?, 5, 5, 16)
print(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2, padding='same')(input).shape)
# >>> (?, 6, 6, 16)
```