# Feature map after concatenation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I have a beginner question, but I'm not able to figure this out.

The input image is 512*512. On the input image 2 separate operations are performed and concatenated:

1. 3*3 convolution with stride 2 which has 13 filters
2. max-pooling operation

After concatenation the result seems to be 16 feature maps, I'm not exactly sure how?

Any suggestions, answers or reading material would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the layers are applied *one after another*, the output won't have `16` feature maps, but `13`. But if they are done *in parallel*, it's fairly possible if the number of input channels `C=3`.

Let's go through the layers one by one:

- The input is `(B, 512, 512, 3)`, where `B` is the batch size.
- The convolutional layer transforms this input tensor into `(B, 256, 256, 13)` or `(B, 255, 255, 13)`, depending on the padding used (see the formula in this question: [A formula to find the size of a matrix after convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47274772/712995)).
- Max-pooling changes spatial dimensions just like the convolutional layer, but it doesn't change batch size and the number of channels. So the output will be `(B, 256, 256, 3)` or `(B, 255, 255, 3)`.
- Assuming that conv and max-pool layers have the same parameters, and concatenation is done along 4-th axis, the concatenation result will be either `(B, 256, 256, 16)` or `(B, 255, 255, 16)`, because `16=13+3`.

Comment: Very concise.Thanks